# Android Running Window prints a lot of things

Tags: android-studio

I remember I had a request for access to something, I approved it, and since then a lot of things have been printed for me in the run window and I do not want that to happen. How to turn it off? How to get back to the point where only the things I print are displayed there?

Comment: It would be good if you posted a picture to explain better what you mean